# np.ones_like() not returning an array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

According to numpy manual, ones_like() should return an array, which is similar to log(). However, when I apply them to pandas groupby, I get different formats. Do I write anything wrong?

```
y = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2], 'b':[2,3,1,1,2]})
print(y)
   id  b
0   1  2
1   1  3
2   2  1
3   2  1
4   2  2

log_y = y.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: np.log(x))
print(log_y)

        id         b
0  0.000000  0.693147
1  0.000000  1.098612
2  0.693147  0.000000
3  0.693147  0.000000
4  0.693147  0.693147

one_y = y.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: np.ones_like(x))
print(one_y)

id
1            [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
2    [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]]
dtype: object
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think that `ones_like` doesn't return an array.

Comment: Can you show what you expected to get instead?

Comment: I expect np.ones_like(x) returns the same format as np.log(x). Only the values are different. So print(one_y) should return 
\ id b 
\ 0 1 1
\ 1 1 1
\ 2 1 1
\ 3 1 1
\ 4 1 1

Answer (score 0):

I haven't studied the `groupby` docs, but with a bit of exploration I find `apply` iterates on the "groups", each of which is a dataframe.

```
In [795]: y.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.shape)
Out[795]: 
id
1    (2, 2)
2    (3, 2)
```

`ones_like` takes the shape of the argument, and uses that to make a new array.  Each of the arrays has the shape shown above.

```
In [794]: one_y.to_numpy()
Out[794]: 
array([array([[1, 1],
              [1, 1]]), 
       array([[1, 1],
              [1, 1],
              [1, 1]])], dtype=object)
```

The `log_y` case apparently reassembles those 2 frames back into one.  I suppose that's documented.